# Distributing an Excel add-in (.xlam) whose code cannot be viewed by the user

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection, excel-addins

I am fairly experienced with Excel and VBA and I know how to create add-ins. However, I haven't found a satisfactory solution for protecting my VBA code once it is in an add-in. How can I make this code inaccessible to the user?

Comment: Use VSTO to create an Add-In. Excel Addins can be easily cracked.

Comment: Just type `vsto excel add in tutorial` in Google and you will get lot of tutorials to create a VSTO AddIn

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth. What is it about VSTO add-ins that make them safer from cracking? And can I take an existing VBA project (with many modules) and bring it over to visual studio? Also, if the Excel Add-in uses worksheets to read and write information, will this be a problem with a VSTO add-in?

Comment: `What is it about VSTO add-ins that make them safer from cracking?` This warrants a detailed comment. It is not only about cracking but it has more powerful development options e.g. access to UI panes and newer controls etc. Unlike VBA, where the code is stored in the document file itself, programs written with VSTO are stored in separate CLI assemblies which are not that easy to crack. [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) is a good read.

Comment: `can I take an existing VBA project (with many modules) and bring it over to visual studio?` Yes. If you know Vb.Net or C# you can easily adapt it.

Comment: `Also, if the Excel Add-in uses worksheets to read and write information, will this be a problem with a VSTO add-in?` Nope Not at all. You can do all that and much more using a VSTO Add-In.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect your VBA code against viewing, however it is relatively easy to crack.

You can easily Google out how to protect a VBA module.

Alternatively, you can create an Add in using Visual Studio. Yet again, .Net code can be decompiled in seconds. Thus, you would need to use a code obfuscator.

Comment: Link Only answers are frowned upon in stackoverflow. This should be more of a comment. BTW OP is fairly experienced. Do you really think OP doesn't know how to enter a password in the VBE and is asking how to enter one? Your link is not an answer to the OPs query :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout How did you determine that OP is fairly experienced?

Comment: `@SiddharthRout How did you determine that OP is fairly experienced? – Tarik 1 min ago` Good Question! Read the question again... this time more slowly :)